# Django : can't return redirect in a sub function exception. The first function continues

Tags: django, exception, redirect

I've got a function **a()** that calls other functions **b()** , **c()** and **d()** this way (I schematize):

**a()**

```
def a(request):
    try:
        b(request)
    except Exception:
        messages.error(request, 'error')
    try:
        c(request)
    except Exception:
        messages.error(request, 'error')
    try:
        d(request)
    except Exception:
        messages.error(request, 'error')
    return redirect('namespace:url_name')
```

**b()**

```
def b(request):
    try:
        do_something()
        messages.success(request, 'I did')
    except Exception:
        messages.error(request, 'Couldn\'t do the thing')
        return redirect('namespace:url_name')
```

But if an exception triggers in **b()** , its redirection doesn't work and **c()** and **d()** are still executed in **a()**.

Did I miss something in my **redirect** or **exception handling** comprehension ?
Because even if I set a **redirect** in all **a** functions' Exceptions, the behavior doesn't change.

Comment: Exactly what is `a` supposed to do, run `b`, `c` and `d` unless there is a redirect in any of the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return the result of `b` in `a`, so, regardless what `b` returns, it will still process `c`, and `d`. The `return redirect` will return, but it will return out of `b`, it does not return out of the callers of `b`, that doe snot make much sense.

We thus should check if `b` returns something, if that is the case, return the result, otherwise continue:

```
def a(request):
    try:
        result = b(request)
        if result is not None:
            return result
    except Exception:
        messages.error(request, 'error')
    try:
        result = c(request)
        if result is not None:
            return result
    except Exception:
        messages.error(request, 'error')
    try:
        result = d(request)
        if result is not None:
            return result
    except Exception:
        messages.error(request, 'error')
    return redirect('namespace:url_name')
```

Comment: No ! **b** **c** and **d** are not supposed to return anything. They just execute DB writing, records change, mail alerts and others. I supposed that if they couldn't execute what they are supposed to do, they could stop **a** and trigger a return directly to the template page and show what went wrong. But as you say - and if I understand well - , only first caller (**a()**) can do this. Right ?

Comment: @Abpostman1: well if `c`/`d` don't return anything it will still work. If you don't return anything (explicitly), the function returns `None`, so we check if `None` was returned, if not, `a` returns the result of that call.

Comment: @ willeM_ Van Onsem . All understood. Thanks for your time